# Node.js API call within protractor

Tags: protractor

Is it possible to call node.js apis within protractor/jasmine spec? I wanted to use some of the node.js apis for making IO and OS calls within protractor..

Answer (score 0):

You can. Just require the modules you will use and the use them.